# convert list of maps to one map in dart?

Tags: dart

If I have a list of key/value pairs, how would I convert them to a single map?

eg `[{'ore': 'value'}, {'pure':'value'}, {'steel':'value}]. =>`

```
{'ore': 'value',
'pure':'value'
'steel':'value'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the reduce function

```
var v =[{'ore': 'value'}, {'pure':'value'}, {'steel':'value'}];

var w = v.reduce((a,b){
  a.addAll(b);
  return a;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just build a new map containing all the individual map's entries:

```dart
List<Map<Something, Other>> listOfMaps = ...;

var combinedMap = {for (var map in listOfMaps) ...map};
```